# XML how to establish if a node exists in VBA before using an Xpath command on it

Tags: vba, parsing, xpath, nodes

I've some XML that *sometimes* has specific content that's present and other times it's not present in the XML. When this data is not present it causes my VBA parsing routine to barf. I therefore need to test a specific path to see if it exists prior to trying to grab the data.

```
Dim objxmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60   

XMLHttpRequest.Open "GET", SignedURL, False

XMLHttpRequest.send (SignedURL)

objxmldoc.loadXML (XMLHttpRequest.responseXML.XML)

xmlNamespaces = "xmlns:ns2='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd' " _
                      & "xmlns:ns1='http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01'"
objxmldoc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", xmlNamespaces


Set NoOfASINs = objxmldoc.selectNodes("//ns1:GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult")

i = 0
For Each n In NoOfASINs
    Set objxmlASIN = objxmldoc.selectNodes("/ns1:ASIN")
    Set objXMLPrice = objxmldoc.selectNodes("/ns1:Product/ns1:CompetitivePricing/ns1:CompetitivePrices/ns1:CompetitivePrice") 

    Debug.Print objxmlASIN(i).text + "," + objXMLPrice(i).text 
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Sometimes there's nothing underneath `/ns1:Product/ns1:CompetitivePricing/ns1:CompetitivePrices` ... so I need to test first.

```
<GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
       <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B002NJHGN6" status="Success">
              <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
                     <Identifiers>
                            <MarketplaceASIN>
                                   <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
                                   <ASIN>B002NJHGN6</ASIN>
                               </MarketplaceASIN>
                        </Identifiers>
                     <CompetitivePricing>
                            <CompetitivePrices>
                                   <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="true" condition="New" subcondition="New">
                                          <CompetitivePriceId>1</CompetitivePriceId>
                                          <Price>
                                                 <LandedPrice>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>17.69</Amount>
                                                    </LandedPrice>
                                                 <ListingPrice>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>17.69</Amount>
                                                    </ListingPrice>
                                                 <Shipping>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                                                    </Shipping>
                                             </Price>
                                      </CompetitivePrice>
                               </CompetitivePrices>
                            <NumberOfOfferListings>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="New">16</OfferListingCount>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="Any">16</OfferListingCount>
                               </NumberOfOfferListings>
                        </CompetitivePricing>
                     <SalesRankings>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_improvement_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>10299</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_and_garden_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>51823</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>1939047031</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>28</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                        </SalesRankings>
                 </Product>
          </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
       <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B003F9MNF4" status="Success">
              <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
                     <Identifiers>
                            <MarketplaceASIN>
                                   <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
                                   <ASIN>B003F9MNF4</ASIN>
                               </MarketplaceASIN>
                        </Identifiers>
                     <CompetitivePricing>
                            <CompetitivePrices></CompetitivePrices>
                            <NumberOfOfferListings>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="New">2</OfferListingCount>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="Any">2</OfferListingCount>
                               </NumberOfOfferListings>
                        </CompetitivePricing>
                     <SalesRankings>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_improvement_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>141917</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_and_garden_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>892073</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>1939038031</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>868</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                        </SalesRankings>
                 </Product>
          </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
       <GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult ASIN="B002F9nNFY" status="Success">
              <Product xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
                     <Identifiers>
                            <MarketplaceASIN>
                                   <MarketplaceId>A1F83G8C2ARO7P</MarketplaceId>
                                   <ASIN>B002F9nNFY</ASIN>
                               </MarketplaceASIN>
                        </Identifiers>
                     <CompetitivePricing>
                            <CompetitivePrices>
                                   <CompetitivePrice belongsToRequester="true" condition="New" subcondition="New">
                                          <CompetitivePriceId>1</CompetitivePriceId>
                                          <Price>
                                                 <LandedPrice>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>113.99</Amount>
                                                    </LandedPrice>
                                                 <ListingPrice>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>113.99</Amount>
                                                    </ListingPrice>
                                                 <Shipping>
                                                        <CurrencyCode>GBP</CurrencyCode>
                                                        <Amount>0.00</Amount>
                                                    </Shipping>
                                             </Price>
                                      </CompetitivePrice>
                               </CompetitivePrices>
                            <NumberOfOfferListings>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="New">2</OfferListingCount>
                                   <OfferListingCount condition="Any">2</OfferListingCount>
                               </NumberOfOfferListings>
                        </CompetitivePricing>
                     <SalesRankings>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_improvement_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>170655</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>home_and_garden_display_on_website</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>1098520</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                            <SalesRank>
                                   <ProductCategoryId>1939038031</ProductCategoryId>
                                   <Rank>1031</Rank>
                               </SalesRank>
                        </SalesRankings>
                 </Product>
          </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult>
       <ResponseMetadata>
              <RequestId>efa320b7-0162-49fc-a328-2f8d93f55f2f</RequestId>
          </ResponseMetadata>
   </GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse>
```

Comment: "the XML below causes much heartache" - how so ? You should be able to check whether your Xpath query returns a hit or not.  Would help your question a to include the code you're using.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code - hopefully it'll be clearer about me wanting to 'test' to see if a path exists first.

Comment: `SelectNodes` return an empty collection if no hits were found, so test that `objxmlASIN.Length` is not zero before trying to access any of the content

Comment: Hi Tim, I found a few references to the .length suffix on the net, but (embarrassingly) I don't know how to test  objxmlASIN.Length ...can you give a quick example of generic VBA code to test it's is not zero?!! (still finding my feet & parsing XML has been a head trip!)

Comment: Your XML screenshot is hard to follow in that format - consider using something like https://www.samltool.com/prettyprint.php instead.

Comment: Don't forget to pick one of the answers as accepted when your problem is solved.

Comment: Please pick one of the answers as accepted already. Walking away from your question is rude

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a `For Each` loop, what's going on with this index counter?
2. Use relative XPaths (starting with `./`).
3. Use `SelectSingleNode` if you only expect one result.
4. Don't use objects that might be set to `Nothing`.

Better:

```vb
Set PricingResults =  doc.SelectNodes("//ns1:GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult")

For Each Result In PricingResults
    Set ASIN = Result.SelectSingleNode(".//ns1:ASIN")
    Set Price = Result.SelectSingleNode(".//ns1:CompetitivePrice") 

    If Not ASIN Is Nothing And Not Price Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print ASIN.text + "," + Price.text 
    End If
Next
```

In an unrelated note, I'd recommend to drop the Hungarian notation. So much typing and no real benefit.

Comment: Hello Tomalak, thank you for your contribution...as you've surely gathered, I'm relatively new to coding.....I welcome the chance to enhance the code I use. That said, I'm getting a Compile error (syntax error) with     **If Not ASIN Is Nothing And Not Price Is Nothing**       .....your  use of "Not" & "Nothing" in the code....can you clarify what's going on there?!

Comment: `SelectSingleNode` returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find a match, whereas `selectNodes` returns an *empty collection* (not `Nothing`)

Comment: Thank you...this looks interesting, I've sorted the compile error (it was missing a 'then' ....off to have a dabble :-)

Comment: When I run the your suggested code, it's got a problem with this line... **Set PricingResults = objxlm.selectNodes("//ns1:GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult")** ....if it helps, my original question now has the XML pasted within (& more code pasted in at the top too...just to assist you seeing what I'm up to).

Comment: @peskywinnets Yes, I've renamed your variables. Don't just copy and paste my code. ;) Also, what's "a problem"?

Comment: From your added XML, one XPath was not right. ([Compare](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35755601/revisions#rev-arrow-92af8977-d863-4b08-abc3-43abfc13fc51)).

Comment: works like a charm (so much more elegant than my initial code), one last question, how to I pull out an attribute with the following Xpath.../GetCompetitivePricingForASINResponse/GetCompetitivePricingForASINResult/Product/CompetitivePricing/CompetitivePrices/CompetitivePrice@belongsToRequester   (the result should be either true or false) ...what command do I need to use in the loop?

Comment: [`getAttribute()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on `Price`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a few permutations, this one seems to do what I want... **belongsToRequester = objxmldoc.selectSingleNode(".//ns1:CompetitivePrice").Attributes.getNamedItem("belongsToRequester").text**

Comment: No, that's incorrect. I think you misunderstood my previous comment. :)

Comment: because I'm not familiar with any of this, I didn't fully understand how to implement your suggestion, so I took to Google (Alas, most of this stuff relating to parsing XML is not VBA, so then I have to try & pick the bones out of what I'm seeing). Anyway, all is good here, because for all I may have misnterpreted your comment, what i have here now works, which was to use  **belongsToRequester = result.selectSingleNode(".//ns1:CompetitivePrice").Attributes.getNamedItem("belongsToRequester").text **...though  if you have a different command more aligned with your suggestion, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: *"`getAttribute()` on `Price`"* means `Price.getAttribute("CompetitivePrice")`. I had hoped that I did not have to spell it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectNodes` return an empty collection if no hits were found, so test that `objxmlASIN.Length` is not zero before trying to access any of the content

```
If objxmlASIN.Length >0 Then
    Debug.print "OK"
Else
    Debug.print "No Match!"
End If
```

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch...what should objxmlASIN be declared as when using the **.length** suffix  (I presently have it as **Dim objxmlASIN As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList** )

Comment: Thanks...i have done & what he provided is working great :-) (thank you for your contribution too)